# Where can I find some articles of Weil.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Where can I find the articles of Weil:

> Variétés abéliennes et courbes algébriques
>
> Sur les courbes algébriques et les variétés qui s'en déduisent.

on Internet?

Comment: They were published together in book format. As far as I know there is no electronic format. They are also not easy to read.